# Passing command line arguments in to a bash script command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Lets say I have a variable storing the name of a compiled C++ program.
`executable="myprog.out"`

My script `tt` needs to create a transcript of the C++ program and exit it (without the user having to type `exit` to exit the bash `script` command).

So far I've achieved this by doing by calling the bash `script` command inside `tt` script like so,

```
#!/bin/bash
script -q -c $executable transcript
```

This method works provided that the C++ program doesn't take command line arguments. If I have a variable holding the command line arguments needed for the program as,
`progArgs="arg1"`

How do I call the script command and have it enter the command line arguments for `$executable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-c` option actually takes a shell command as its argument, so you can pass arguments like that:

```
script -q -c "$executable --opt1 --opt2 -f test" transcript
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do the the `--` for options. Thank you!!

Comment: @syntaxerror Whether you use `--` or `-` depends on the program, this was just an example.